# file not found when click new in webpart gallery

Tags: 2007, web-part

I am getting an error when i click new webpart in webpart gallery. I want to deploy my custom webpart to sharepoint webpart gallery.
I try to look in sharepoint log. Sadly, there is no further info in sharepoint log. They dont even throw correlation number error.

Comment: what error are you getting? Did you check the ULS logs? Do you have a custom master page? Did you try to add the web part with the default master page set for the site?

Comment: Only "file not found" error.. I try to upload image in this question for further clarity but my rep not allow it.

Comment: Are you talking about the web part gallery or add new webpart menu?

Comment: when I click new webpart in webpart gallery. In NewDwp.aspx. The problem has solved now. After I googling, i know that the culprit is "return of smartpart" component. Many thanks all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using smart-part in your SharePoint site? If so, maybe you should install [AJAX 1.0](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=883) in your web front-end server to solve that error. This is a common error when you dealing with smart-part. If not, just ignore my answer.

Comment: yes, i'm using smartpart in my sharepoint site. Gonna try your advice..